# Wildfly Server 404 New missing/unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: maven, jboss, server, wildfly, web-deployment

First of all, I have to admit that I am really new to Wildfly/JBoss. That is why I spent several hours finding the solution with no luck.

I wanted to deploy the project on the server, but I got the 404 - Not found error.
I do not know, what I did wrong, because the standalone.xml and the other files are correct.

The log tells the story better:

```
    11:50:21,414 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
11:50:31,719 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final
11:50:31,798 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.1.0.Final "Kenny" starting
11:50:32,907 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found cta-web.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called cta-web.war.dodeploy
11:50:32,932 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
11:50:32,956 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO version 3.2.2.Final
11:50:32,966 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.2.Final
11:50:33,001 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
11:50:33,005 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
11:50:33,002 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
11:50:33,012 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
11:50:33,016 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
11:50:33,009 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS010153: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
11:50:33,084 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.3.Final
11:50:33,086 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.21.Beta1
11:50:33,085 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
11:50:33,099 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.15.Final starting
11:50:33,099 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.15.Final starting
11:50:33,117 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
11:50:33,164 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.1.5.Final)
11:50:33,169 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
11:50:33,211 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
11:50:33,232 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
11:50:33,316 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS017527: Creating file handler for path /Users/tothkristof/Documents/Programming/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/welcome-content
11:50:33,346 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017525: Started server default-server.
11:50:33,361 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017531: Host default-host starting
11:50:33,619 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
11:50:34,071 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /Users/tothkristof/Documents/Programming/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments
11:50:34,074 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "cta-web.war" (runtime-name: "cta-web.war")
11:50:34,687 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.2.4.Final
11:50:37,759 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for primary
11:50:38,159 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.cta-web.war" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.lang:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
11:50:38,160 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.cta-web.war" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.lang:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
11:50:38,161 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.cta-web.war" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.io:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
11:50:38,162 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.cta-web.war" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.io:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
11:50:38,163 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.cta-web.war" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.codec:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
11:50:38,163 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.cta-web.war" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.codec:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
11:50:38,164 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.cta-web.war" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.beanutils:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
11:50:38,164 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.cta-web.war" is using a private module ("org.apache.commons.beanutils:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
11:50:43,492 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Expired Entry Monitor) ARJUNA012210: Unable to use InetAddress.getLocalHost() to resolve address.
11:50:43,576 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
11:50:43,582 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "cta-web.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"cta-web.war#primary\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.default]"]}
11:50:43,611 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "cta-web.war" (runtime-name : "cta-web.war")
11:50:43,613 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.default (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."cta-web.war#primary".__FIRST_PHASE__] 

11:50:43,619 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
11:50:43,620 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
11:50:43,620 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.1.0.Final "Kenny" started (with errors) in 22512ms - Started 197 of 248 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 83 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
11:50:43,896 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment cta-web.war (runtime-name: cta-web.war) in 59ms
11:50:43,926 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "cta-web.war" (runtime-name: "cta-web.war")
11:50:43,927 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.persistenceunit."cta-web.war#primary".__FIRST_PHASE__ (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."cta-web.war".POST_MODULE] 

11:50:48,641 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015003: Found cta-web.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called cta-web.war.dodeploy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel really stupid. I had the old standalone.xml file and I forgot to replace with the new one. Everybody makes mistakes, so be sure to check if your standalone file is correct.